# How to deploy an app using ionic framework to Amazon? (elastic beanstalk prefered)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node.js app, which creates HTTP server and handles socket connections, and I have an Ionic Framework Application (angular.js)
Could you please give me some guide how to run it on AWS?
On my local system, I simply run the command - `node app.js` and then go to ionic app folder and type `ionic serve`

Please, I'm finally stacked trying dozen of ideas and even Amazon Support could not help me, for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to create a web app using node.js as a server and [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com) as front-end framework, and finally run this everything on AWS ElasticBeasntalk

Ionic is written with AngularJS (very useful [free course](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) by CodeSchool). AngularJS is a library, which you upload to user's browser including it as `<script/>` There is no need to install it on the server environment.

Here is what I finally came up with:

1. You create your node application `app.js` - it's the server side.
2. Copy `/www` folder from ionic project
3. In app.js you need to through this folder and the index.html file to the server, which is initialized by your app.js

`app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});`

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'public'));
```

Now you have two .js applications - Angular (front-end) and Node (back-end) in one repository and running by simple `node app.js` command.

All you need to to do to deploy it to ElasticBeanstalk - create a `package.json` file, zip you project, create a Node.js environment and upload this version to your running environment.

P.S.
To zip properly - go into your folder and use `zip -r 1.zip .` command

P.P.S. `package.son` file sample:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.10.6",
    "request":"2.51.0",
    "redis":"0.12.1"
    ----your libraries here ---
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Elastic Beanstalk(EB) support node.js already but I didn't see angular.js in the list, and seems `ionic` is a plug-in/framework for angular.js (need you confirm) which is not included as well.

So here is my thought to fix your problem (I didn't implement it, and need your confirmation)

- create new application in service `Elastic Beanstalk` with node.js as Predefined configuration platform
- add EC2 key pair in ec2 instance. (it is important, with it, you can ssh and login the ec2 instance to check the error log)
- Set the config file in EB, follow below documents.

  [Customize AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Configuration Files](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/11/elastic-beanstalk-config-files)

  [Customizing the Software on EC2 Instances Running Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html)

With the config file, you can customise EB and install the missing package.

Take a try and let me know the result.

More, if you can take time to read the documents about AWS Service `Cloudformation` and its template. It will help you a lot to understand how EB works.